# Possible to override bounding box selection area in fabricjs - controls option

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, custom-controls, fabricjs

Here, we are working in fabric.js with creating design tool.We have create custom selection area for canvas object in fabric.js. I read source code in fabric.js, it generates square box for bounding box, but I want change to my custom.  Selection area appearance. Can someone please advise me?

[image: HERE DANCING DOTS SELECTION AREA]

We want custom selection area appearance.

[image: HERE FABRIC.JS DEFAULT SCRIPT]

We have tried this code **`context.setLineDash()`** for selection area.

```
if (fabric.StaticCanvas.supports('setLineDash') === true) {
    ctx.setLineDash([4, 4]);
}
```

Refer code from [Github](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2700).But won`t working fine for my working area.

Here we have attached **`Borderdasharray`** Property creation in fabric function

```
fabric.Object.prototype.set({  
        borderColor: 'green',  
        cornerColor: 'purple',  
        cornerSize: 33,
        transparentCorners: false,padding:4,
        borderDashArray:[50,25]          
    });
```

But we need to create animated dancing dots/moving dots for that selection area in fabric.js.

How can we create custom selection area in fabric.js?

Comment: Assuming you just want a dashed selection box, you can just set the borderDashArray property of the object (ex. obj.borderDashArray = [4,4]).

Comment: Yes @Ben.. I have created dashed selection box, but i need to create dancing dots-dashing/Moving dots-dashing selection box. How it is possible ?

Comment: See http://fabricjs.com/clipping.  You could create an animation to act on the borderDashArray and get some sort of effect like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an animated "borderDashArray", the MDN Documentation on [lineDashOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineDashOffset) provides a [Marching Ants example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineDashOffset#marching_ants) with the following ([fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bp4u8tsr/)) :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var offset = 0;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.setLineDash([4, 2]);
  ctx.lineDashOffset = -offset;
  ctx.strokeRect(10,10, 100, 100);
}

function march() {
  offset++;
  if (offset > 16) {
    offset = 0;
  }
  draw();
  setTimeout(march, 20);
}

march();
```

Based on fabricjs [object_interactivity.mixin.js](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/src/mixins/object_interactivity.mixin.js) *drawBorders* function, the above can be applied as follows :

```
fabric.Object.prototype.set({  
        borderColor: 'green',  
        cornerColor: 'purple',  
        cornerSize: 33,
        transparentCorners: false,padding:14,
        borderDashArray:[50,25]          
    });
// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c',{width: 500, height: 500});
textbox = new fabric.Textbox('Hello, World!', {
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  top: 80,
  left: 80,
  fontSize: 50,
  textAlign: 'center',
});
canvas.add(textbox);
textbox2 = new fabric.Textbox('Hello, World!', {
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  top: 160,
  left: 160,
  fontSize: 50,
  textAlign: 'center',
});
canvas.add(textbox2);
canvas.renderAll();
canvas.setActiveObject(textbox);
var offset = 0;

  (function animate() {
    offset++;
    if (offset > 75) {
      offset = 0;
    }  
    canvas.contextContainer.lineDashOffset = -offset;
    canvas.renderAll();
    fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(animate);
  })();

  canvas.on('after:render', function() {
    canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = 'green';
        canvas.contextContainer.setLineDash([50,25]);
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
      var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();            
      canvas.contextContainer.strokeRect(
        bound.left + 0.5,
        bound.top + 0.5,
        bound.width,
        bound.height
      );
    })
  });
```

[fabricjs border animation fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Da7SP/398/).

Comment: In your idea will be applied some static borders only. Is it applicable for each and every object of canvas?.Or else it may be set as dynamic for every object ?

Comment: What do you prefer ?

Comment: Hi @neopheus... do you get my idea ? we have tried your code many times it will shown individual object only. but we need to set each and every object selection area will be like dancing dots/moving dots in canvas.

Answer (score 4):

For customization :

```
  borderDashArray: Dash stroke of borders
  cornerDashArray: Dash stroke of corners
  cornerStrokeColor: If corners are filled, this property controls the color of the stroke
  cornerStyle: standrd 'rect' or 'circle'
  selectionBackgroundColor: add an opaque or transparent layer to the selected object.
```

For use this :

```
fabric.Object.prototype.set({
    transparentCorners: false,
    borderDashArray: ......
```

Comment: Yes @neopheus, Used your code already and i have create borderdasharray property in Canvas fabric.js. But i need to set animated "Borderdasharray" property like dancing dots/moving dots.How to achieve it kindly give some idea for that ?